# Django-nonrel vs Django with PyMongo/Ming for use with MongoDB

Tags: django, mongodb, django-models, pymongo, django-nonrel

I'm about to start a project with Django and MongoDB. From what I can tell, there are two ways to use Django and MongoDB together. One way is the fork of Django called Django-nonrel which supports NoSQL databases, and the other is to just use the standard version of Django with PyMongo (and optionally Ming for models, etc.).

I have used the second option lightly in the past, but this is going to be a large project. I honestly don't know too much about Django-nonrel, but it seems like using the primary Django project would be better from a stability standpoint, as well as from a new features standpoint.

Is there an advantage to using Django-nonrel over just base Django with PyMongo thrown in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a biased opinion, but I would use Django with PyMongo.
The main reasons are the following. First, what you stated about using the standard Django version versus a fork. And secondly, the fact that PyMongo is the official Python driver for MongoDB. It is written and maintained by MongoDB. It ensures that any new feature in MongoDB will be available in PyMongo.

Comment: My only other question really becomes how to use plugins that normally create tables. For example, can Auth be configured to work with PyMongo somehow?

Comment: Luke,
By 'Auth', do you refer to the Django authentication plugin, or to MongoDB's way of authenticating a user.
If is the latter, you can find some examples at:
http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/examples/authentication.html
If you are referring to the Django library, I was hoping that someone else could help you, because I am not familiar enough with that library.
You may want to open a separate question for that.
Questions with no answers in Stack Overflow get more visibility.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I wasn't aware MongoDB had its own authentication framework. I've since decided to just use SQL for the backend though, MongoDB isn't quite as amazing as it is made out to be.

Comment: By the way I really thought I marked this as the correct answer awhile ago, sorry!